# How to create an Explorer window without Navigation Pane using Shell command Explore

Tags: autohotkey, windows-shell

My app Folders Popup is using the command `ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Explore(strPath)` to create a new Explorer window. I need a way to tell this new instance of Explorer to comply with the Navigation Pane setting decided by the user (to show or not show the pane) in previous Explorer windows.

Actually, this setting is not taken into account by default in the new instance created by the Shell command and users of my app who prefer to use Explorer without this navigation pane are annoyed to see it reappear when my app is opening a new Explorer. Is there any solution to this (except sending keys to the Explorer, what I prefer to avoid)?

Comment: Is there a difference if you use `Run, %myPath%`?

Comment: Oh! Yes. Then it behaves as if I would open the new Explorer manually, without the navigation pane. I just have to check if there are any side effect to use Run here. But I think it should not.  You should make your comment a solution! Thank you MCL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler is sometimes better ;)

The `Run` command isn't just for executables, it can also open non-executable files like images/documents (as long as their file type is associated) and especially folders:

```
myFolderPath = C:\Path\To\Folder
Run, %myFolderPath%
```

Generally, it makes sense to use built-in commands or functions if available, before incorporating ActiveX, COM objects or DLL calls; those should provide extra functionality, and not replace what AHK can do out of the box. That, of course, occasionally requires some digging into the [docs](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/), but it's worth it! AHK is one of the most well-documented automation scripting languages for Windows.

Comment: You are right. I will still need to call the Shell COM object for its .Navigate command that allow me to change folder in the current Explorer. But, for a new Explorer, the standard `Run` command is just what I need.  Thank you again MCL.